# Running HTML/JavaScript in a Perl File

Tags: php, arrays, perl, forms

I have an array in my Perl file that I'm using to populate a drop down menu in another PHP page.

So I have a perl.pl file that is called by ---> php.php. Now, this is the code in my PHP file

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/perl perl.pl $arg1 $arg2");
echo $output;
```

In my Perl file, this is what I pass at the end to get the drop-down menu:

```
    print "<SELECT id='process_type'>\n";
    foreach $value (@xvalues) { 
        #Removing any trailing white spaces from the option list
        $value_no_space =~ s/\s+//g;
         print "\t<OPTION value='$value_no_space'>$value</OPTION>\n";
         $i++;
    }
    print "</SELECT>\n";
    my $s = document.getElementById('process_type');
    print $s;
    print "\n";
```

I was hoping that when I selected an option from the menu on the PHP page, that variable would come back to and be stored in $s. However, this is not the case. I do understand that PHP is client side and Perl is server side, so thats why I'm unable to get the result back. Is there a work around? I really do need to have the selected option in the same Perl file in order to complete some other tasks I need to do ...

Comment: Do you mean [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) or [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)?

Comment: Troll detector is tingling...

Comment: Sorry, I meant Javascript. Changing title now ...

Comment: More of a Perl guy, here--but all the same--why are you sys-ing out to perl? Are you unaware of all the PHP utilities?

Comment: Probably not! But there is a graphing utility in Perl that I am using and I got my files to parse successfully after a lot of effort! The thought of doing it all over again in PHP scares me!

Answer (score 1):

PHP *is* server side - I think you are confusing PHP with [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript).

To get it available serverside, give your `select` a `name` attribute.

For what reasons are you executing that portion of code with Perl via PHP system call?

I think what you want is best to handle all the HTML output and POST handling with PHP. Then you can use your Perl graphing utility after.

Comment: Alex, in my Perl file : I changed my '<select id= ..>' to 'print "<SELECT name='process_type'>\n";' and also '  my $s = document.getElementById('process_type').value;
  print $s;' But I still can't get the value in the Perl file. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Hmm, well I actually have parsed some data in my Perl program. I want to execute this data based on some user input. So I'm passing that data to my PHP file, hoping that I can get the output of the drop-down list and continue my Perl program. Do you think there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: Hmm, the thing is. After I parse my file in Perl, I NEED user input to proceed with changing this data. So if I handled that in PHP. I would need to call my Perl script again and redo all the parsing, so that I can continue after collecting the user input. I think this is wasted resources since I'm parsing the same thing twice. Could you perhaps suggest why putting a 'name' attribute, doesn't allow me to gather the selected data?